# Не получается придать ID объекту, прежде чем загнать его в Local Storage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Здравствуйте, я учу JS сейчас наткнулся на проблему, которую не могу решить. Надеюсь на помощь + объяснения или ссылку на обучающий материал. 
спасибо.

Из полей в HTML получаем данные и загоняем их в переменные a,b,c
после этого данные загоняются в объект и объект уходит в local Storage

для того что бы различать объекты в Storage, мне нужно придать каждому следующему свой ID. ID я получаю, он динамический, но привязать его к объекту у меня не получается. в чем ошибка?

```
var notesData = {
    text: c,
    date: a,
    time: b
}

notesData.setAttribute("ID", newMemberID);

localStorage.setItem('notesData', JSON.stringify(notesData));

var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('notesData');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));`
```

Comment: `notesData.ID = newMemberID;` ?

Comment: _в чем ошибка_ - при вызове `notesData.setAttribute(...)` в консоли браузера должна была появиться ошибка о том, что _setAttribute_ не является функцией, если такой ошибки нет, то стоит привести в вопросе больше кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В JS свойство к объекту добавляется не так. Свойства добавляются следующим образом:

```
myObject.key = value
```

или

```
myObject['key'] = value
```

В вашем случае можно записать так:

```
notesData["ID"] = newMemberID;
```

Функция "setAttribute" - задает атрибут DOM элементу.
Прочитать подробнее про объекты и DOM можете [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/object) и [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties)